# Active Directory without global catalog

Tags: active-directory

Are there any Active Directory configurations supported, where forest contains no Global Catalog?

EDIT: Since it was a prevalent comment to the question, I will answer it here: I am working on a product and QA requested that it must work in environment with no GC is present at all. Hence the question: are there conceivably any environments which don't have one.

Comment: Why should you want such a thing?

Comment: Unless you've somehow created such a config, you are on to support, you are being told that they won't touch you with a 10 foot pole, and you want to prove them wrong...

Comment: What is the QA scenario? Do they have a customer using ADAM? Or is your app running at a remote site that could be cut off from the GC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active Directory Directory Services: No. You need at least one GC

Active Directory Application Mode: Yes (to my knowledge, you don't need a GC)

As Massimo asks; Why would you want such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

You need at least on GC, your first domain controller is setup by default as a Global Catalog server.

As many have said, I can't understand why you want to do this. If you have multiple domains in your forest, you really need a GC per domain for them to communicate effectively and if you only have 1 domain in your forest, then your GC really doesn't add much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bizarre request.  According to the [TechNet article on GCs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728188(WS.10).aspx), in a single-Domain environment the only *absolute* requirement for a GC *seems* (and I do say "*seems*") to be for GAL lookups in Exchange, but all the same I'm failing to understand why creating a GC could be something you would want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The GC is the system against which you actually authenticate.  If you have no GCs you can't authenticate.  Hit TechNet and you will see this pervasively throughout the documentation.

Comment: afaik, GC does not authenticale, DC does

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if they meant an AD **site** where there are no GC's, which would be not a good thing but possible.

Answer (score 0):

In a single domain environment without Exchange you don't need a GC, even with multiple sites. GC has got nothing to do with locating domain controllers in this scenario.

Comment: are you saying it is possible to set up functional environment where GC will not be running?

Comment: Yes, in a single domain with no apps (such as Exchange) that require GC.